# Rails method JSON rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a listings_controller in my rails app along with a Listing model.
The db consists of listings each with name, latitude, longitude, etc.

There is a method in my listing_controller that when called should return a JSON object to the caller.

the JSON object should get its data from the corresponding Listings model. However, I want the JSON object to only contains the name, latitude, longitude of each listing and not other attributes of the model. How can I restrict this?

Right now when the method returns a JSON object it includes all the attributes of each listing.

Here is the current implementation:

```
def list  
@listings = Listing.order(:name)  
render :text=>(@listings).to_json()
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to replace:

```
@listings = Listing.order(:name)
```

with:

```
@listings = Listing.order(:name).select([:name, :latitude, :longitude])
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gem. It's a templating system for easily and flexibly generating json (among other things).

There is also a free [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl).

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) gem.

If you don't want all that, you could just manually create a hash:

```
render :text => {name: @listing.name, lat:@listing.lat, long:@listing.long}.to_json
```